# Function for addition and getting average of a user defined single dimensional array

Tags: c, arrays, function-call, function-definition

**This is the question "Write a function which gets an integer array and number of elements as parameters and calculates and displays sum and average of all the integers of the array in C language"**

*Below is the code which I have done, it's running but consists of bugs which give false answers*

```
#include <stdio.h>

void SumAvg(int x, int arr[x]) {
  int i, sum = 0;
  float avg = 0;

  for (i = 0; i < x; ++i) {
    sum += arr[i];
  }
  avg = (float)sum / x;

  printf("The sum is %d", sum);
  printf("\nThe average is %.2f", avg);
}

int main() {
  int x, i;

  printf("Enter number of elements");
  scanf("%d", &x);

  int arr[x];

  for (i = 0; i < x; ++i) {
    printf("Enter integers for array[%d]", i + 1);
    scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
  }
  SumAvg(x, arr[x]);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Enable compiler warnings. It should be called like this: `SumAvg(x,arr)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First , your function calling is wrong .It should be `SumAvg(x,arr)` instead of `SumAvg(x, arr[x]);`.

also in function declaration , in some compiler `void SumAvg(int x, int arr[x])` might be problematic.

Comment: The declaration of the function is perfectly fine. This syntax is used for self-documenting purposes (it is clear that it expects array of the size passed).

Comment: @EugeneSh.I know this is strange , but I'm receiving this error `a parameter is not allowed`

Comment: hane, Are you using a modern C compiler? `void SumAvg(int x, int arr[x])` is allowed in C99 and optionally in C11 or later.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica VS 2019 , actually I'm using newest version of VS.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica you mean the syntax is right in c , but in some this won't be allowed or it is wrong?

Comment: VS 2019 (a pre-C99 standard compiler) complies with some C99 features, yet MS has for its own strategic reasons, not moved its C compiler up to C99 yet (even after 21 years later).

Comment: Research [variable length array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array#C99).

Answer (score 0):

For starters the function should be declared the following way

```
void SumAvg( const int arr[], size_t n );
```

That is the parameter that declares the array shall have the qualifier `const` because the array is not changed in the function.

The number of elements of the array should have the type `size_t`.

The function definition can look the following way

```
void SumAvg( const int arr[], size_t n )
{
    long long int sum = 0;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        sum += arr[i];
    }

    double avg = n == 0 ? 0 : ( double )sum / n;


    printf( "The sum is %lld\n", sum );
    printf( "The average is %.2f\n", avg );
}
```

That is within the function the variable sum should have the type `long long int` to decrease the risk of overflow.

In general the user can pass to the function the number of elements equal to 0. In this case if not to check this value the function will have undefined behavior.

This call of the function

```
SumAvg(x, arr[x]);
```

is invalid because instead of passing the array you are passing its non-existent element with the index `x`.

Taking into account the provided function definition above a valid call of the function will look like

```
SumAvg( arr, x );
```